# How to iterate array values in loop in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am getting the values from the csv data set configuration, splitting the values, storing them in an array, and using that in a continuous loop.

I tried using the while controller, and it takes the first value fine, but for the next loop, the same values are taken again. I also tried FOR each controller, and it is not working.

Note : I am using Javascript Language

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of doing this is using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

If you have a variable from CSV called `myVar` which looks like `foo,bar,baz`

You can generate the JMeter Variables suitable for using with ForEach Controller using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the following [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code:

```
vars.get('myVar').split(',').eachWithIndex { value, index ->
    vars.put('var_' + (index + 1), value)
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Also I would recommend reconsidering using JavaScript because:

1. It's performance anti-pattern, you [should be using Groovy language for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).
2. JavaScript support [has been removed from JDK 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372) so you won't be able to use JavaScript in the latest versions of Java